# Creating 2 boxes side by side with tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, tikz-styles, adjustbox

I want to create 2 boxes side by side (image below) in order to have the red box on the right of the blue one :

[image]

I wrote this code but I don't know how to do it (I am just specifying the width to fit in the general page):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf, tikz, adjustbox}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}


\begin{document}
\tcbset{colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries, width = 12cm}
\begin{tcolorbox}[before=\adjustbox{valign=t}\bgroup, after=\egroup]

\textbf{Démonstration}

\end{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries, width = 5cm}
\begin{tcolorbox}[before=\adjustbox{valign=t}\bgroup, after=\egroup]

\gap
A écrire 
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciated ! Thank you very much.

Comment: Avoid unwanted spaces and/or new lines between them, use `%`

Comment: Thank you : this is a bad habit that I have in latex. @SebGlav do you even use % in long latex documents ? Because I tend to be a bit lost while using it...

Comment: These are mandatory for some constructions, in order to avoid unwanted space. I don't use them when not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the option `box align` in the [package documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) on page 86 in the PDF. You can set this to `top`, `bottom` and `center`. Here is an example using `center`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz, adjustbox}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\tcbset{colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,width=5cm,nobeforeafter}

\begin{tcolorbox}[box align=center]
\textbf{Démonstration}
\end{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,width = 5cm}
\begin{tcolorbox}[box align=center]
\vspace{1cm}
A écrire 
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

This produces the output:
[image]